# What files are cached by browsers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, browser-cache

I am developing a web app using the AngularJs-framework. I'm currently trying to figure out how to prevent web caching and I am doing so by setting a hash in front my filenames.

What I have seen thus far is that most people only do this for image-, javascript- and css-files, for instance here:

http://davidtucker.net/articles/automating-with-grunt/#workflowCache

My question is, is there other kind of files that I should take into consideration?
Doesn't web browsers cache html-files as well?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid cching of any file/filetype ? In that case you should do the same for all your files yes, but I find it a very bad practice unless your content is changing that much that there's no point for user to cache anything...

Comment: I'm mostly wondering if I should prevent caching of html-files as the project contains a lot of partial html-files which are used in various places could potentially be quite hard to manage if they are cached.. In short I am hoping that AngularJs has some inbuilt way of dealing with browser caching that I'm not able to find information about.

Answer (score 1):

Follow Google's guidelines for [Optimizing Caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching).

Some key points:

- **Set caching headers aggressively for all static resources**.
  For all cacheable resources, we recommend the following settings:

  - Set Expires to a minimum of one month, and preferably up to one year, in the future. (We prefer Expires over Cache-Control: max-age because it is is more widely supported.)
  - Do not set it to more than one year in the future, as that violates the RFC guidelines.
  - If you know exactly when a resource is going to change, setting a shorter expiration is okay. But if you think it "might change soon" but don't know when, you should set a long expiration and use URL fingerprinting (described below). Setting caching aggressively does not "pollute" browser caches: as far as we know, all browsers clear their caches according to a Least Recently Used algorithm; we are not aware of any browsers that wait until resources expire before purging them.
- **Set the Last-Modified date to the last time the resource was changed**: If the Last-Modified date is sufficiently far enough in the past, chances are the browser won't refetch it.
- **Use fingerprinting to dynamically enable caching**: For resources that change occasionally, you can have the browser cache the resource until it changes on the server, at which point the server tells the browser that a new version is available. You accomplish this by embedding a fingerprint of the resource in its URL (i.e. the file path). When the resource changes, so does its fingerprint, and in turn, so does its URL. As soon as the URL changes, the browser is forced to re-fetch the resource. Fingerprinting allows you to set expiry dates long into the future even for resources that change more frequently than that. Of course, this technique requires that all of the pages that reference the resource know about the fingerprinted URL, which may or may not be feasible, depending on how your pages are coded.

Read Google's full article for other points, especially regarding inter-operability.